# ¿Cómo mostrar datos de un JSON en PHP?

Tags: php, json, api

miren tengo un dilema, necesito mostrar a un cliente su saldo de una cuenta de envíos a través de la API muestra algo así:

```
   {
  "envia_account_saldo": [
    {
      "account": "DIV8DCNY",
      "alias": "Cliente Cliente",
      "balance": "-190.0",
      "credit_balance": "-190.0",
      "prepaid_national_balance": "562.82",
      "prepaid_international_balance": "0.0",
      "currency": "MXN",
      "order_type": "Credit"
    }
  ]
}
```

Deseo que solo se le muestre especificamente los datos de:

"account": "DIV8DCNY",
"prepaid_national_balance": "562.82",

Con que los muestre en un formato plano de texto esta bien.

La URL de la API es así:

GET https://envios.corporativomarva.mx/api/v1/get_account_saldo?api_key=ncdjncskmxcdjknc026f201cv5sdsc0d2sc0ds&account=DIV8DCNY

La clave API la quite por seguridad.

No se como integrarlo la verdad me he perdido totalmente.

Intente hacer algo como esto pero no muestra nada, todo en blanco, anda mal pero no puedo identificar que es ya que soy nuevo en esto del PHP:

```
<?php

//Get data from API cURL
$url = 'https://envios.corporativomarva.mx/api/v1/get_account_saldo?api_key=ncdjncskmxcdjknc026f201cv5sdsc0d2sc0ds&account=DIV8DCNY';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($json, true);

//Print data from API on HTML page
echo '<h1>Saldo de la cuenta</h1>';
echo '<p>Saldo actual: $'.$data['prepaid_national_balance'].'</p>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he resuelto simplemente agregando estos valores

```
echo '<p>Saldo actual: $'.$data['envia_account_saldo'][0]['prepaid_national_balance'].'</p>';
```

El código completo quedo así

```
<?php

//Get data from API cURL
$url = 'https://envios.corporativomarva.mx/api/v1/get_account_saldo?api_key=ncdjncskmxcdjknc026f201cv5sdsc0d2sc0ds&account=DIV8DCNY';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($json, true);

//Print data from API on HTML page
echo '<h1>Saldo de la cuenta</h1>';
echo '<p>Saldo actual: $'.$data['envia_account_saldo'][0]['prepaid_national_balance'].'</p>';
```

Answer (score 2):

primero que todo la forma correcta de llamar una api en php, es haciendo uso de cURL ó con la librería Guzzle php , file_get_contents es para obtener contenido de archivos, mas no para consumir APIs. Para Obtener esos dos datos, lo primero que hay que saber , es si la API entregada tiene la opción de hacer filtros, si no tiene filtros y hay que ligarse a la respuesta expuesta, entonces hay que recorrer esa estructura,

```
    $array = [];
    $arrayFiltered = [];
    $json = json_encode(miestructura)["account_saldo"]; // Usar json_encode o json_decode , dependiendo de la estructura, json_decode recibe un segundo parametro, si se pone true, convierte la estructura de objeto a array asociativo
    forEach($json as $obj){
    $account = $obj["account"];
    $prepaidNationalBalance = $obj["prepaid_national_balance"];
    $arrayFiltered = ["account" => $account, "prepaidNationalBalance" => $prepaidNationalBalance];
    array_push($array,$arrayFiltered);
    }

echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: hice algún cambio intentándolo hacer por cURL, pero me sigue mostrando los datos en blanco, como comente soy muy nuevo en esto y no logro hacer que funcione me lo muestra en blanco y tu código no entiendo como integrarlo o donde